# Spring MVC. Passing Collection to jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm trying to write a web application using Spring MVC and ran into a problem
When passing any collection to jsp catching the exception:
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.films_jsp**
and HTTP status 500, but if I pass any other object that is not a collection, then everything is fine

*films.jsp:*

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FILMS</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Films</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>year</th>
        <th>genre</th>
        <th>watched</th>
        <th>action</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="film" items="${filmsList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${film.id}</td>
            <td>${film.title}</td>
            <td>${film.year}</td>
            <td>${film.genre}</td>
            <td>${film.watched}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="/edit/${film.id}">edit</a>
                <a href="/delete/${film.id}">delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<a href="/add">Add new film</a></body>
</html>
```

*pom.xml:*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Filmography</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>Filmography</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

*Controller.java:*

```
...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView allFilms() {
        List<Film> films = new ArrayList<>();

        films.add(new Film(0, "Pie", 1991, "Fantasy"));
        films.add(new Film(1, "Passion", 2003, "Drama"));

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("newFilms");
        modelAndView.addObject("filmsList", films);
        return modelAndView;
    }
...
```

I suspect that the problem is in the Spring or in the versions of the connected dependencies. If it matters i use Tomcat

Comment: `javax.servlet:jstl` ? use `jakarta` do not use `javax`, Tomcat 10,x.

Comment: What are the details of the 500 error, and what is logged by Spring? What you have looks correct to me.